# Below are 4 functions with the same functionality, but different implementations. Can somebody suggest more different approaches?

Tags: haskell

There are 4 Functions with identical functionality, but 4 Different Implementations based on different approaches, like "using guards", "using inline function and "where", using "case-of" expression, and using "null :: Foldable f => f a -> Bool" and guards.
I did a couple of versions the same BY FUNCTIONALITY function using case-of and where with patterns.
Willem Van Onsem added 1 more version and fix a bug in "guard" version. Many thanks to him.
Can somebody add more versions using different approaches?
Thank you in advance.
Al

```
-- 4 versions of myList 
-- using case-of 
myList1    :: [a] -> String
myList1 xs = case xs of []  -> "empty"
                        [x] -> "one"
                        xs  -> "more"

-- using guards and patters
-- error here was fixed by Willem Van Onsem
myList2 :: [a] -> String
myList2 xs
    | []  <- xs = "empty"
    | [_] <- xs = "one"
    | otherwise = "more"

-- using null :: Foldable f => f a -> Bool and drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
-- by Willem Van Onsem
myList3 :: [a] -> String
myList3 xs
    | null          xs = "empty"
    | null (drop 1 xs) = "one"
    | otherwise        = "more"

-- using where and patterns
myList4 :: [a] -> String
myList4 xs = what xs 
    where what []  = "empty"
          what [x] = "one"
          what xs  = "more"
```

Comment: Can you describe your motivation in asking the question? What would you like to understand better or what problem are you solving? There are infinitely many functions trivially "different" functions which have the same external functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You want more versions of the same function? Here have *infinitely many*, conveniently generated by Template Haskell:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module MyListGenerator where

import Language.Haskell.TH

myListGenerator :: Int -> Q [Dec]
myListGenerator nTot = pure <$> go nTot (mkName "myList")
 where go 0 myName = return $ FunD myName
         [ Clause [ListP []] (NormalB . LitE $ StringL "empty") []
         , Clause [ListP [WildP]] (NormalB . LitE $ StringL "one") []
         , Clause [WildP] (NormalB . LitE $ StringL "more") []
         ]
       go n myName = do
         myArg <- newName "xs"
         locFunName <- newName "what"
         locDecl <- go (n-1) locFunName
         return $ FunD myName
           [ Clause [VarP myArg]
                    (NormalB $ AppE (VarE locFunName) (VarE myArg))
                    [locDecl]
           ]
```

Example use:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import MyListGenerator

myListGenerator 37

main = print $ myList "bla"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am not sure, I completely understood, but what I meant was, to use different methods, approaches to write the very same function. This way I can compare the power of the Haskell. So far I've got 4 different "types" of functions. May be 3.5. :). The Idea is to see what other people can see, what you cannot see. I am new in Haskell and trying to digest (in good sense) the expertise of others. Espeshialy so good and smart people around. I will definetly look closely at your approach. Thanks again. Al

Comment: @Forestshield I think this is a tongue-in-cheek answer, possibly meant to underline that it's hard to precisely define what a "different method" is.

Comment: No, It was a serious question. I was asking an expertise of more knowledgable people, if they can see more ways to do it by using something I do not know yet. For instance the way to do this function using by using "null :: Foldable f => f a -> Bool" by Willem Van Onsem was completely unknown for me. That's all. Anyway, somebody closed my question. I guess, It is not a proper way to ask help like this. :)

Comment: Just for curiosity. I compiled and run your app and this is output in console: 1-exe ; exit;
"more"
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...3 completed.

[Process completed]            I did not understood where are generated functions. Anyway. There is too many things, I could not understand from this code. Anyway. Thanks.